# How to use CSS to position div popup when using :hover...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, popup

I am trying to create a popup in CSS. In this case, it's a small div containing text labeling the image you're hovering. However, I am definitely doing it wrong. I am either positioning the :hover div in CSS incorrectly (I've tried different positions (fixed, absolute, float, clear, etc.), but it keeps showing up inside the main div. I could wrong with my HTML, as I'm placing it within the main div that you hover for the popup to appear. But I'd think it has to be there to show up when you hover the main div. Any help is appreciated. Code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="topIcons topIconsHover topLabelHover">
    <a href="image.html"><img src="icons/image.png" /></a> 
    <div class="topLabelHover">Image</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topIcons {
    padding:14px 6px 10px 6px;
    float:right;
 }

.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    cursor:pointer
}

.topLabelHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;       
    width:80px;
    height:24px;
    position:fixed;
        top:40px;
}
```

I am fine with using JavaScript (or JQuery) if it's necessary, but it seems like something simple enough for CSS. Also, is it better to use CSS over JavaScript (or Jquery) when possible because perhaps it's faster? I could be mistaken there, but would be interested to of the best practice.

edit* Still having trouble so thought I'd explain further what I'm trying to do with my page layout and perhaps it'll help. I have a series of icons in a navigation bar, all floated right. Upon hovering, I'd like the background to change (which I've managed in CSS with the "topIconsHover" class) and for a "label" div to appear beneath the related hovered icon div in the navigation bar when hovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you want something like this:

```
.topIcons {
    padding:14px 6px 10px 6px;
    float:right;
 }

.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    cursor:pointer
}

.topLabelHover {
    display:none;
}

.topIconsHover:hover .topLabelHover {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#555555;       
    width:80px;
    height:24px;
    top:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kHPZK/

Comment: The "display:none" seems to just get rid of the main div? When I remove that, it seems to create a div to the right of the main div, pushing the main div left. I ultimately just want the label div to present itself below (in a relation position to the main div) when hovering.

Comment: My bad. Just made an edit. Also: you probably should remove that topLabelHover class from the parent div -- otherwise this won't work.

Comment: I still can't get it to work... what would the html need to be? Also, just to understand the "display:none" is this created so that using that class anytime other than when hovered, it is never displayed? I guess that is why it removes everything because my parent div has that class. However, how would I then structure the html to allow for hovering over this div to get the background effect and the label div?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This is a quick jsFiddle I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/kHPZK/. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my main post, so I apologize. I want the label to be beneath the hovered div and not within. For instance, the link you provided, that navigation bar, when you hover the items in the navigation, you get a small popup labeling each item. That's what I'm looking to do, position a label div (when I hover the main div) under the main div.

Comment: You can just play with top and left properties in that last CSS rule to tweak the label position.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ozarek/2/edit)

Code used:

HTML:

```
<div class="imagebox">
  <a href="image.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x120/444/cf5" /></a> 
  <div class="label">transparent Image label</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .imagebox{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
    background:#eee;
  }
  .label{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:0px;
    padding:18px;
    background:#fff;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.imagebox').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
  var label = $(this).children('.label');
  m = (e.type === 'mouseenter') ?
  label.stop(1).fadeTo(300,0.9) :
  label.stop(1).fadeTo(300,0) ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `:hover` class in CSS when you want to change the css *of the element the :hover rule applies to.* You came up with an interesting workaround in your code: using `.topLabelHover:hover` to manipulate the CSS of multiple elements when any of them were hovered over. This will work, except you need to account for the fact that this will change the css of all elements with that class and not just the one hovered over. You can do this by making sure the CSS of the popup is the only one that changes by setting the CSS of the triggering element to the exact same thing:

```
.topIcons {
    position: absolute;
    padding:14px 6px 10px 6px;
    float:right;
 }

.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    cursor:pointer
}

.topLabelHover {
    display: none;
}

.topLabelHover:hover, .topIconsHover {
    display: block;
    background-color:#555555;       
    width:80px;
    height:24px;
    position:absolute; //makes the div appear 40px from the top of parent
    top:40px;
}
```

However, IMHO this is very confusing to read. Your code would be a lot clearer, shorter, and simpler if you just used jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div class="topIcons topIconsHover">
    <a href="image.html"><img src="icons/image.png" /></a> 
    <div class="topLabelHover">Image</div>  
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".topIconsHover").hover( function() {
    $(".topLabelHover").addClass("hovered");
});
```

Css:

```
.topIcons {
    position: absolute;
    padding:14px 6px 10px 6px;
    float:right;
 }

.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    cursor:pointer
}

.topLabelHover {
    display: none;
}

.hovered {
    display: block;
    background-color:#555555;    //this,   
    width:80px;                  //this,
    height:24px;                 //and this should be factored out into a separate class!
    position: static;            //revert to normal positioning.
}
```

The performance of the CSS version would be infinitesimally better, but since the Jquery version still takes far less than 100ms to show the pop it will feel just as instantaneous. :D

EDIT: If you want to make the pop-up appear under the div, just put the `<div>` of the pop-up directly after the triggering div instead of inside it, and change the `.hovered` css to this:

```
.hovered {
    background-color:#555555;       
    width:80px;
    height:24px;
}
```

If you want to make a tooltip-like effect, just google 'jquery tooltip' and choose whatever extension best meets your requirements. :D

Comment: How would I get the div to appear outside of the parent div (directly underneath)? Because I still can't get it to get outside the parent div (perhaps it shouldn't be nested in the html then?). I'm looking to do something more similar to a suppose a dropdown menu (minus the list, it's just a label) I suppose. I am fine with using Jquery, it does seem far simpler than working it through CSS.

Comment: @user1066982 I edited the answer slightly, does that help at all?

Comment: It does help as I see what the jQuery is doing. For instance, it is targeting "topIconsHover" so that upon hovering that class, it'll open the popup, regardless of where the div is within the HTML... so I don't need to have it nestled within the main div. However, I'm still struggling to see the hovered div. It is probably because I'm positioning it wrong and it's off the screen or something. Can you help with that?

Comment: Tooltip is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I wasn't really sure what that was when you first said it, just googled it a bit though. Thank you!